# Installing pgadmin 3 for Ubuntu 11.10 and postgresql 9.1

Tags: postgresql

I've installed pgadmin3 on a remote ubuntu client and succesfully connected to the postgres db using:

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

Problem is that when connecting to the postgres 9.1 server it notifies me that I don't have the latest pgadmin and some of the features might not work using this client.

From reading the pgadmin site I should download the postgres binary at http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/pgdownload.do but that's only a installer bin.

How can I install the pgadmin from that binary as the ubuntu one is not the latest? Alternatively, is there any other location where I can find the pgadmin binaries?

Comment: Jorge, it's a specific problem for ubuntu 11.10 and postgresql 9.1. Check the post properly before editing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a PPA having 1.14.0beta1 version but it does not have 11.10 support:

https://launchpad.net/~rhonda/+archive/pgadmin3

So you can try to add this PPA as 11.04 or download directly the packages and install them by hand:

https://launchpad.net/~rhonda/+archive/pgadmin3/+packages

Comment: Can you walk me through it? I'm just an enthusiast. I've downloaded the tar.gz an unpacked it. Checking the INSTALL file. Says I should install postgresql... it's on another machine and I'd rather not install it on the client.

Comment: Which tar.gz files? If you are asking for my answer, you can see there .deb packages. Just pick **pgadmin3-data_1.14.0~beta1-1~ppa1~natty1_all.deb** and according to your OS architecture **pgadmin3_1.14.0~beta1-1~ppa1~natty1_i386.deb** or **pgadmin3_1.14.0~beta1-1~ppa1~natty1_amd64.deb**

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad that it worked.

Answer (score 6):

this ppa works for me (ubuntu 11.10 32bit):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/postgres
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

Comment: I'm afraid that the ppa does not exists anymore.